# What does (String... arg) mean in a function definition?

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String... arg)
```

I have never encountered the `...` part in the function definition. Could anyone give some insight into this notation?

Answer (score 3):

The `...` indicates that you are passing 0 or more arguments of the type and the method will access them as an array of objects of the type.  You may pass them as an array or as a sequence of objects of the declared type. 
I.e.:

In your `main` method use

```
String firstArg = arg[0];
```

to access the first argument.

Look at the [documentation of varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) for more info.